# How do you revert ONLY directories in an SVN working copy?

Tags: svn, recursion, directory, properties, revert

I want to revert a **directory and all sub-directories** in an SVN working copy so they match the repository but I **don't want to touch any files** inside those directories.

One of my SVN applications recursively set an SVN property on every directory in my working copy but I want to revert those changes to stop it highlighting them and trying to commit the changes to the SVN properties. Simply changing it to match the HEAD doesn't work.

Any ideas? I've read through various SVN resources but none of them seem to deal with this edge case.

Comment: Cheers for the response. Any shell was fine. It's a Windows system but I had Bash.

Comment: You should really change which answer you've accepted

Comment: Why? The one I've accepted was entirely suitable. The one that has 40+ upvotes does not answer the question. Read it. Think about it. Read it again. Test it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `find` combined with `svn revert`:

```
find . -type d | grep -v .svn | xargs svn revert
```

This won't touch any files inside the directories unless you use the `-R`option (which is equivalent of `--depth=infinity`).

Answer (score 104):

Works on all platforms:

```
svn revert . --recursive
```

**(Note that this will revert everything, not just directories.)**

Comment: Why the heck did this answer only have 1 up-vote? The other answers make me want to stick a needle in my eye!

Comment: @Petrucio Doesn't this also touch files? I don't want to recursively revert everything under the current directory, just the directories.

To quote Greg Stein: "But a recursive revert on a directory could revert a whole lot more than you might think (toss all local mods to all files and dirs under it)."

The net result, assuming that's applicable, would be the complete destruction of my working copy. Oops.

Comment: @Rushyo: Indeed you are correct. I wanted to revert everything including files, but on my cursory glance I did not properly read the entire question.

Comment: Since the mods refuse to remove this:
*** DO NOT DO THIS IF YOU HAVE MY ISSUE OR YOU WILL DESTROY YOUR WORKING COPY ***

Comment: In case we needed any more proof that people up-vote based on prettiness over code that actually works. Wow.

Comment: @Rushyo There's no need to be so upset about this answer. If it didn't solve your problem then don't mark it as the answer - no need to request it be removed or provide snarky remarks. You did not explain your issue well enough. You should have explained that you don't want to REVERT files, instead you said that you didn't want to TOUCH files (ie. Change the file's timestamp). It's quite obvious this command recursively reverts everything under a directory.

Comment: /EDIT You know what, I'm not even going to bother replying to that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is what turns up first when you search for `svn revert recursively` on Google, in which case this answer is the correct one. I suggest changing the question title if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, **make a copy of your working copy somewhere safe**. :)

You can edit properties on svn working copies using commands like this:

```
REM Delete all mergeinfo properties recursively
svn propdel svn:mergeinfo -R
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows from the command line you could do this:

```
for /d /r %i in (*) do svn revert %i
```

If you call that from a batch file use `%%i` instead.  **Please back up first!**

This command is *dirty* and will go through all directories, even unmodified ones or the ones not under `svn`.  You could use something like this Ruby script to do in a cleaner way:

```
`svn st`.split("\n").grep(/^ M\s+(.*)/) { $1 }.find_all { |i| File.directory? i }.each do |i|
  system "svn revert #{i}"
end
```