# Failed to use svn:ignore for directory

Tags: svn, ignore

I tried to ignore a folder in a svn repo with:

```
svn propset svn:ignore -R nbproject .
```

But that failed massively. Now when I call svn status, each single folder in the repo appears to be modified. That means they are all shown with `M` in the `svn status` list.

It looks like the `svn:ignore` property has been added to all the folders, now they look "modified", how can I reverse that?

Comment: Have you got any other uncommitted changes you want to keep, preventing you from doing a full revert?

Comment: yes, some files are changed and still uncommitted, its not possible to just remove the property? Then the folders should be unchanged again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the simplest solution is to iterate over everything in the working copy that is a directory and revert each one. Reverting a modified directory won't touch its file contents. This assumes you haven't created any new directories.

There are a few questions like that, such as [How do you revert ONLY directories in an SVN working copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4818587/534406) Note that the answer with over 100 votes obviously reverts everything, which isn't what you want, but there are other answers suitable for Linux and Windows platforms.

Obviously, you could back up your working copy before testing these solutions.